# Problem with Math.Truncate, getting a double into an Integer

Tags: c#, .net, windows

First of all you should now im new in Programming, and english is not my mother language, im from germany.

I`m trying to write a programm, which says me how many Days, Hours and Minutes have passed, concluding to the user input. For the User input i have the double variable (time) and the integer (day), in this example i typed in 14.40 (its like 2.40pm, in germany we write it 14.40) and 2 (for tuesday). 
Now i want to programm to Write the following sentence:
"Since Monday 1 Day, 14 Hours and 40 minutes have passed!"
Insted of that he prints out "Since Monday 1 Day, 1440 Hours and 0 minutes have passed!"

To split the double i used Math.Truncate to get the full hours (14), and then i subtract that from the the user input (14.40), to get the Minutes (40).

I can't find a solution in the Internet for that Problem, i hope you guys can help me with that.

[image: In this picture you can see my Code, and the console]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int day;
        double time;
        int VDays;
        double VHours;
        double VMinutes;

        Console.Write("Which day do we have? (1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, ...):\n");
        day = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Which time is it?\n");
        time = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        VDays = day - 1;
        VHours = Math.Truncate(time);
        VMinutes = time - VHours;

        Console.WriteLine("Since Monday" + VDays + " Day, " + VHours + " Hours and " + VMinutes + " minutes have passed!");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dominic, welcome to SO. Please do not post images of code. Post the code itself. Please take a moment to read this and modify your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please paste your code as a snippet in your question please

Comment: Note that `Convert.ToDouble` uses your current locale setting for the decimal separator which might be ',' instead of '.'. Also, `TimeSpan.Parse` might be the better choice when dealing with time input.

Comment: Use the difference between two dates in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLQKRlNxIKA

Answer (score 1):

Having tested it I can confirm this is a locale issue as [Klaus Gütter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142950/klaus-g%C3%BCtter) mentioned.

Since `Convert.ToDouble` uses your German locale settings and commas are the decimal separators in German, it ignores the dot and interprets 14.40 as 1440.

You can recreate the problem with:

`time = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat);`.

You can specify the locale to be used to fix the problem, here with [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.8):

`time = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

You also need to multiply VMinutes by 100 for it to work, since substracting the integer value from the time will leave you with a number between 0 and 1 (i.e `14.40 - 14 = 0.40, 0.40 * 100 = 40` minutes have passed).